# Actionscript3 listening for custom event

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, event-listener, starling-framework

I am using starling, but that should not change anything. I have a custom event dispatched from WorldManager.as (gist: https://gist.github.com/raimonds1503/5101967) and I am listening to it on Game in init method.

By tracing everything, the event is dispatched and event listener is added, but the callback method is never called. Am I listening on wrong object?

Thank you.

Comment: You'll get better help if you post some of your code so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: There is this gist link with all the code thats relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are listening for the event after it's already fired. You need to add your event listener earlier.

```
public class Game extends Sprite 
{       
    public function Game() 
    {
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        trace("Starling running");
        GV.worldManager = new WorldManager();
        GV.worldManager.addEventListener(NewWorldEvent.CHANGE, addToStage); 
        this.addChild(GV.worldManager);
        GV.worldManager.setWorld(new World());
    }

    private function addToStage(e:NewWorldEvent):void 
    {
        this.addChild(e.world as World);
        trace("Handling new world event!");
    }
}
```